# IntelliJ Live Template for dart named constructor: lists class' fields

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, dart, live-templates

I want to generate a custom named constructor in Dart.
I have many dto class to implement and each should provide a named constructor like: `ClassName.fromMap()`.

For example for this class:

```
class Student {
  final String name;
  final int age;
}
```

The generated constructor should be:

```
Student.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) :
    name = map['name'],
    age = map['age'];
```

How can I retrieve the list of the field of my current class as strings? Is that even possibile?
Of course I can have a variable number of fields.

My template looks like:

```
$CLASS$.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) :
        $INITIALIZATION_LIST$
```

binding `$CLASS$` to `dartClassName()`.

Now I'd like to bind `$INITIALIZATION_LIST$` to something like:

```
getClassFieldList().forEach((fieldName) => "$fieldName = map['$fieldName']")
```

Can I achieve something like that?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to retrieve a list of Dart class fields using predefined live template functions. You can try developing your own template macro for this. See https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206201699-create-a-new-expression-for-a-live-template-for-actionscript for some hints.
Existing live template functions implementations can be found at https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/tree/master/platform/lang-impl/src/com/intellij/codeInsight/template/macro.

You can also try using [Structural Search and Replace](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/structural-search-and-replace.html) instead of live template

Comment: But has someone succeed in use **Structural Search and Replace**  in Dart files? In the specific IntelliJ menu (Ultimate 2020.3 with Dart plugin) languages ​​such as Java and SQL are available to me, but not Dart, and I don't see how I could work around this limit.